# Specific browser zoom when certain aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

I'm currently pulling my hair out with this one. Im a new web developer using bootstrap themes and templates just to get a feel for the industry, and have hit a bump in the road that needs an experienced input

Ive got a website that Ive created at the minute, where certain parts of the screens don't resize properly when the aspect ratio is lower than mine (1920px). However zooming out on the browser corrects this issue. For instance 1440px needs to be zoomed out to 75% in order for everything to be correct. A number of images have fallen out of the bootstrap framework due to a positioning request from my friend, although ive used @media queries to correct a number of these issues but thats clearly where the problems have arisen.

I'm aware that I should go back and fix this bugs from scratch but I seriously will go crazy if I have to do that. I do know that it is possible to resize the browser zoom being used if the aspect ratio is below a certain level however Ive heard thats not the way to go.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed with this one? Is there an "entire page/html" zoom query that can be put in place rather than a browser zoom?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom):

```
body {
  zoom: 0.75;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're just starting out, I would recommend you right click on elements that are not appearing as expected, and inspect them in your Chrome console (or whatever browser you're on). You can then first adjust styling properties and transfer over the appropriate changes to your actual code once you confirm that the adjustments you make do what you want.

Comment: OP already mentioned that _"I'm aware that I should go back and fix this bugs from scratch but I seriously will go crazy if I have to do that."_

Comment: OP didn't mention whether he or she is aware of using console. Any other fix is only going to be a quick fix approach as opposed to actually addressing OP's core issues.